# DAML key not found on Keyserver

Tags: daml

**gpg --keyserver pgp.key-server.io --search 4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51**

Above command is not fetching key from Keyserver.

**Error: key "4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51" not found on keyserver**

Answer (score 0):

There looks to be something weird going on with the keyserver. This used to work reliably, but just now I had to try 5 times to get the key.

```
$ ls -a    
.  ..
$ mkdir gpg
$ gpg --homedir gpg --keyserver pgp.key-server.io --search 4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir '/private/var/folders/fr/hnsktbhj611cbgfj6thp_jcr0000gn/T/tmp.HN9B7i113l/gpg'
gpg: keybox '/private/var/folders/fr/hnsktbhj611cbgfj6thp_jcr0000gn/T/tmp.HN9B7i113l/gpg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: data source: http://pgp.key-server.io:11371
gpg: key "4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51" not found on keyserver
gpg: keyserver search failed: Not found
$ gpg --homedir gpg --keyserver pgp.key-server.io --search 4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir '/private/var/folders/fr/hnsktbhj611cbgfj6thp_jcr0000gn/T/tmp.HN9B7i113l/gpg'
gpg: data source: http://pgp.key-server.io:11371
gpg: key "4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51" not found on keyserver
gpg: keyserver search failed: Not found
$ gpg --homedir gpg --keyserver pgp.key-server.io --search 4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir '/private/var/folders/fr/hnsktbhj611cbgfj6thp_jcr0000gn/T/tmp.HN9B7i113l/gpg'
gpg: data source: http://pgp.key-server.io:11371
gpg: key "4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51" not found on keyserver
gpg: keyserver search failed: Not found
$ gpg --homedir gpg --keyserver pgp.key-server.io --search 4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir '/private/var/folders/fr/hnsktbhj611cbgfj6thp_jcr0000gn/T/tmp.HN9B7i113l/gpg'
gpg: data source: http://pgp.key-server.io:11371
gpg: key "4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51" not found on keyserver
gpg: keyserver search failed: Not found
$ gpg --homedir gpg --keyserver pgp.key-server.io --search 4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir '/private/var/folders/fr/hnsktbhj611cbgfj6thp_jcr0000gn/T/tmp.HN9B7i113l/gpg'
gpg: data source: http://pgp.key-server.io:11371
(1)     Digital Asset Holdings, LLC <security@digitalasset.com>
          2048 bit RSA key E8372C0C1C734C51, created: 2019-05-16, expires: 2021-05-15
Keys 1-1 of 1 for "4911A8DFE976ACDFA07130DBE8372C0C1C734C51".  Enter number(s), N)ext, or Q)uit > 1
gpg: /private/var/folders/fr/hnsktbhj611cbgfj6thp_jcr0000gn/T/tmp.HN9B7i113l/gpg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E8372C0C1C734C51: public key "Digital Asset Holdings, LLC <security@digitalasset.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
$
```

(using a blank homedir to ensure no interference from existing config)

I would suggest just retrying for now.